# Material-UI Core TextField globally set InputLabelProps shrink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know how to globally override the shrinking of the label with a Material-UI Textfield (or Input if I need to use this)?

I dont want to add this everywhere:

```
...      
InputLabelProps={{
    shrink: true,
}}
```

but I cant seem to figure out the correct override in `createMuiTheme`.

I have tried adding `shrink: true` here

```
overrides: {
    MuiInput: { ...
```

and here

```
overrides: {
    MuiInputLabel: { ...
```

But I cant get it working.

If someone could point my to the docs/code to where they figured this out too, that would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Have the same issue.

I don't want to use the label, and just want to use a regular placeholder. But if the input isn't "shrunk" by default. The placeholder doesn't show up until it's focused.

Comment: I didn't. I no long use material UI (not my choice) but before I changed I ended up creating my own component and using that everywhere.

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify, in version 1 (and later) theme overrides allow you to customize a component's *styles*, not props. This is approach is a lot more powerful as it gives you full control over all Material UI Styles.

In this case, you would need to modify the styles for each TextField variant so the shrink styles are applied by default ([see implementation](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js))

The best solution is to create a custom variation of the component, as Alireza suggested. Here is an example:

```js
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function CustomTextField({ InputLabelProps = {}, ...props }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      InputLabelProps={{ ...InputLabelProps, shrink: true }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Material UI - Custom TextField]

Answer (score 3):

Check the Mui documentation on [theme default props](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-default-props).

> Every Material UI component has default values for each of its props. To change these default values, use the defaultProps key exposed in the theme's components key.

You can try this.

```js
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: 'outlined',
        margin: 'dense',
        size: 'small',
        fullWidth: true,
        InputLabelProps: { shrink: true } // <----
      }
    }
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  Might help to add some context about mui theme

Answer (score 2):

if you want to override some method of the basic component, in my opinion, the best way is to create custom component and change whatever you need then use your own component inside your project . for this react gives you anything you want

Comment: +1 This is my only other option but with version 0 of MUI it was easy to do this and it seems like they wouldn't remove this. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

We can use InputLabelProps property to enable the shrink option

```
const CustomTextField = ({
    label,
    value,
    maxLength,
    required,
    disabled,
    handleChange,
    handleClear,
    error,
    helpertext,
    shrink
}) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            label={label}
            fullWidth
            size='small'
            variant='standard'
            value={value}
            inputProps={{ maxLength: (maxLength && parseInt(maxLength)) || 99}}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: shrink, style: { fontSize: 18 } }} // we can mention this way to shrink the label
            required={required}
            onChange={handleChange}
            InputProps={{
                endAdornment: (
                    (value.length > 0 && !disabled) ? <IconButton onClick={handleClear}>
                        <ClearOutlinedIcon/>
                    </IconButton> : ''
                ),
                readOnly: disabled
            }}
            error={error}
            helperText={helpertext}
        />
    )
}

CustomTextField.propTypes = {
    disabled: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    handleClear: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    helpertext: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    maxLength: PropTypes.string,
    required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really don't want to bother with creating a custom component, you can use theme overrides to get it close. Simply copy the shrink css properties to the MuiInputLabel. Something like this:

```
MuiInputLabel: {
  outlined: {
    transform: 'translate(14px, -6px) scale(0.75)',
    transformOrigin: 'top left',
    padding: '0 2px',
    background: '#ffffff',
  },
},
```

It's not perfect, as the padding is applied to both the shrink and override, but it's very close.

Also, if you aren't using 'outlined', you don't need the padding or background properties and it should look identical to the other fields with 'shrink'.